# unable to process Dockerfile: unable to parse repository info: repository name component must match

Tags: asp.net, docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

Hi I am following the guidance on this blog post, "Managing containerized ASP.NET Core apps with Kubernetes"

https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2016/10/managing-containerized-ASP.NET-Core-apps-with-Kubernetes.html

I am stuck at the stage where you get docker to build the image

```
docker build -t gcr.io/xxxx/hello-dotnet:v1 .
```

This is the error I am getting.

```
unable to process Dockerfile: unable to parse repository info: repository name component must match "[a-z0-9](?:-*[a-z0-9])*(?:[._][a-z0-9](?:-*[a-z0-9])*)*"
```

Contents of my Dockerfile are

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:1:1.0.1-core
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN ["dotnet", "restore"]
RUN ["dotnet", "build"]
EXPOSE 8080/tcp
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://*:8080
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "run"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line of your `Dockerfile` should be:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:1.0.1-core
```